# Code coverage for functional tests

Tags: java, rest, code-coverage, functional-testing, test-coverage

I have a Java RESTful API. I use [REST Assured](http://rest-assured.io/) for my functional tests on each endpoint.
Is there a way to get the code coverage for the classes/methods used behind the scene (controllers, services, DAOs/repositories, etc.) when REST Assured (or any similar tool) makes calls to the API? (I guess the API should be started with some agent or something that reports what happens until it is stopped?).

Comment: You could try using attribute tags above your methods and have Maven evaluate your code coverage.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using [JaCoCo](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/agent.html) (Java agent and Maven plugin) with [SonarQube](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Usage+of+JaCoCo+with+Java+Plugin)

EDIT after Sikandar's comment:
In my case it's a Spring Boot app so when I run the jar file I add the option
`-javaagent:/myapp/lib/jacoco.agent-0.7.9.jar=destfile=/myapp/coverage-reports/jacoco-at.exec`
Reports are generated when the app is stopped. Then I configured SonarQube to use the file `/myapp/coverage-reports/jacoco-at.exec` for its analysis

Comment: Can you share the plugin details you added for getting the code coverage. I am trying to get the same using jmeter functional testing.

Comment: @Sikandar I added more details in my answer.